# Unzipping all .bz2 archives in directory

Tags: batch-file, zip, winrar, bz2

I have a directory called "input" full of subdirectories which contain a number of bz2 archives. Like so:

```
-input
--folder1
---archive1.bz2
----archive1.content
---archive2.bz2
----archive2.content
---archive3.bz2
----archive3.content
--folder2
---archive4.bz2
----archive4.content
---archive5.bz2
----archive5.content
---archive6.bz2
----archive6.content
```

I am trying to write a windows batch script to extract the contents of each archive to a new "output" folder, whilst retaining the internal file structure, so that we end up with this:

```
-output
--folder1
---archive1.content
---archive2.content
---archive3.content
--folder2
---archive4.content
---archive5.content
---archive6.content
```

So far I have this script:

```
for /R "C:\Users\Ed\Desktop\input" %%I in ("*.bz2") do (

  "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x "%%I" *.* "C:\Users\Ed\Desktop\output"
)
```

The extraction works but does not package the contents into their folder1, folder2 etc.

I feel like I need to make the new folder for each archive's parent folder, then set it as the output directory. Something like this:

```
for /R "C:\Users\Ed\Desktop\input" %%I in ("*.bz2") do (
    mkdir "C:\Users\Ed\Desktop\output\parent folder of %%I"
    "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x "%%I" *.* "C:\Users\Ed\Desktop\output\parent folder of %%I"
)
```

But how do I get a handle on the parent folder name?

Answer (score 0):

The `FOR` command supports some *magic characters* that extract parts of the variable %%I.
Use `FOR /?` for help.

In your case this might work:
   `mkdir "C:\Users\Ed\Desktop\output\%%~dI%%~pI"`